# Handle regular expression in ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, rhomobile

In my controller i m taking some records from table. I am trying to send records records to Js and show in my page.

```
 @item_list = TransferDetail.find(:all) - Code to get data from table
```

The output of  @item_list as

```
[{:source_id=>8, :object=>"11375810_0", :prefix=>"a",:unit=>"0", :description=>"xxxxx"}, {:source_id=>8, :object=>"11375810_1", :prefix=>"b", :unit=>"0", :description=>"yyyyy"}]
```

Sending records to JS side

```
WebView.execute_js("replaceItemList('#{@item_list}')")
```

In Js side

```
function replaceItemList(item_list){
  alert (item_list);
 }
```

Alert result as like this

```
[{:source_id=&gt;8, :object=&gt;&quot;11375810_0&quot;, :prefix=&gt;&quot;a&quot;,:unit=&gt;&quot;0&quot;, :description=&gt;&quot;xxxxx&quot;}, {:source_id=&gt;8, :object=&gt;&quot;11375810_1&quot;, :prefix=&gt;&quot;b&quot;, :unit=&gt;&quot;0&quot;, :description=&gt;&quot;yyyyy&quot;}]
```

Any one can suggest me to how can i show in my view page.

I know how to parse below and show in view page.

```
"{\"transferType\":\"D\", \"accountNumber\":\"132\", \"employeeId\":\"23\", \"orderedByPhone\":\"2423453453\", \"deliveryInstructions\":\"fdgfghvbn\"}"
```

Is possible to convert my  @item_list value like this or Let me know some other suggestion

Comment: I don't understand the question title at all. In any case, wouldn't it make more sense to send JSON rather than a string representation of an array of objects?

Comment: Try using to_json `WebView.execute_js("replaceItemList('#{@item_list.to_json}')")`

Comment: @Joshua: This will fail if there's a single quote in any of the fields, so `.gsub("'", "\\'")` is necessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is send table (database records) to front end and to show.
So i did like below
           def transfer
             @item_list = TransferDetail.find(:all)
             preferred_accessories_content = get_preferred_accessories_content
             WebView.execute_js("replaceItemDetails('#{preferred_accessories_content}')")
           end

```
def get_preferred_accessories_content
    preferred_accessories_content = ""
    @item_list.each do |pa|
      preferred_accessories_content+= "<tr>" + "<td> #{pa.description} </td>"+"</tr>"
    end
    preferred_accessories_content
end
```

Here the result of "preferred_accessories_content" is normal html table row, so i can append  this row to my view page through JS.